# Error HTTP ERROR 404 occurred while trying to run the maven project to send html email using thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, maven, jetty, thymeleaf

I am creating a maven project to send html email using thymeleaf templateEngine.
Browser shows the following error while trying to run my project. I use Intellij Idea and Jetty as the server.
    HTTP ERROR 404

```
Problem accessing /adsops/index. Reason:

    Not Found
```

This is what console says. I rechecked my dependencies several times but problem still appears. Please help to figure out where the error is?

```
 [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO]
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building adsops-core 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO]
    [INFO] >>> jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.6.v20151106:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ adsops-core >>>
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ adsops-core ---
    [WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
    [INFO] Copying 2311 resources
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) @ adsops-core ---
    [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ adsops-core ---
    [WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
    [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory E:\Projects\ADpost\ops\dev\src\test\resources
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ adsops-core ---
    [INFO] No sources to compile
    [INFO]
    [INFO] <<< jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.6.v20151106:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ adsops-core <<<
    [INFO]
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.6.v20151106:run (default-cli) @ adsops-core ---
    [INFO] Logging initialized @3121ms
    [INFO] Configuring Jetty for project: adsops-core
    [INFO] webAppSourceDirectory not set. Trying src\main\webapp
    [INFO] Reload Mechanic: automatic
    [INFO] Classes = E:\Projects\ADpost\ops\dev\target\classes
    [INFO] Context path = /adsops
    [INFO] Tmp directory = E:\Projects\ADpost\ops\dev\target\tmp
    [INFO] Web defaults = org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml
    [INFO] Web overrides =  none
    [INFO] web.xml file = null
    [INFO] Webapp directory = E:\Projects\ADpost\ops\dev\src\main\webapp
    [INFO] jetty-9.3.6.v20151106
    [INFO] 2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
    SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
    SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
    [INFO] Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
    Sep 06, 2017 1:15:59 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
    INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
            name: default
            ...]
    Sep 06, 2017 1:15:59 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
    INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
    Sep 06, 2017 1:15:59 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
    INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
    Sep 06, 2017 1:15:59 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
    INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
    Sep 06, 2017 1:15:59 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
    INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
    Sep 06, 2017 1:16:00 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
    INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
    Sep 06, 2017 1:16:00 PM org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version <clinit>
    INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.3.4.Final
    Sep 06, 2017 1:16:01 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
    INFO: HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
    Sep 06, 2017 1:16:01 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator initiateService
    INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
    [INFO] Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
    [INFO] Started o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@2e3cdec2{/adsops,file:///E:/Projects/ADpost/ops/dev/src/main/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{file:///E:/Projects/ADpost/ops/dev/src/main/webapp/}
    [INFO] Started ServerConnector@6a3e633a{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8888}
    [INFO] Started @11100ms
    [INFO] Started Jetty Server
```